# Foreach in List returning same records only in different conditions after iteration

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, asp.net-core-3.1

UPDATE:

1.I have a result object with 100 data records from db.Based on diffrent if condition i have to store that records in a list.I am adding every records in their satisfied condition loop.BUt when I see the final object all 100 records are same.What will be the issue?

2. is there any refatored method for this same logic as i am written some entry level code pls suggest

What I have Tried in my  method:

```
       foreach (var data in MainObj)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.RealKey))
        {
            if (data.ResultStatus == "Failed")
            {
                FailedTestCases.Add(data.TestCases);
            }

            if (FailedTestCases.Count > 0)
            {
                alltcPassed = false;
            }
            else
            {
             
                alltcPassed = true;
            }

            if (isValidKey && alltcPassed)
            {
            
               ResultSummary.TestCases = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FailedTestCases);
                ResultSummary.TestType = data.TestType;
                ResultSummary.ResultStatus = data.ResultStatus;
                result.Add(ResultSummary);

            }
            if (isValidKey && !alltcPassed)
            {
               
                ResultSummary.TestCases = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FailedTestCases);
                ResultSummary.TestType = data.TestType;
                ResultSummary.ResultStatus = data.ResultStatus;
                result.Add(ResultSummary);

            }
            if (!isValidKey && alltcPassed)
            {
                ResultSummary.TestCases = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FailedTestCases);
                ResultSummary.TestType = data.TestType;
                ResultSummary.ResultStatus = data.ResultStatus;
                result.Add(ResultSummary);
            }

            if (!isValidKey && !alltcPassed)
            {
               
                ResultSummary.TestCases = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FailedTestCases);
                ResultSummary.TestType = data.TestType;
                ResultSummary.ResultStatus = data.ResultStatus;
                result.Add(ResultSummary);
            }
        }

      //   this else happen when this condition true the firstone foreach(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.RealKey))

        else
        {
            if (data.ResultStatus == "Failed")
            {
                FailedTestCases.Add(data.TestCases);

                
                    ResultSummary.TestCases = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FailedTestCases);
                    ResultSummary.TestType = data.TestType;
                    ResultSummary.ResultStatus = data.ResultStatus;
                    result.Add(ResultSummary);

            }
            if (data.ResultStatus == "Passed" && FailedTestCases.Count==0)
            {
              
                ResultSummary.TestCases = data.TestCases;
                ResultSummary.TestType = data.TestType;
                ResultSummary.ResultStatus = data.ResultStatus;
                result.Add(ResultSummary);

            }
         
        }
    }
      return  Task.FromResult(result.FirstOrDefault()); //here result having 100 datas but all are same need to get 100 diffrent record
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you storing the results of your check calculations in some collection? Or are you supposed to be E.g. setting a bool to true and then looping until it goes false and at that moment stopping the loop and saying "failed"? Your question is quite "big" - can you accurately explain what it is you're confused about? Is the paragraph in all caps a description of the single output value you're expecting, a 1, 2, 3, or 4?

Comment: i have to store and assign  all passed and failed testcases based on data key is null or its valid (eg key is there like 123 but its not valid )

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to put your `List FailedTestCases = new List();` outside of the foreach loop in order for you to have all the FailedTestCases. And if you want the list to have your FailedTestCases and custom error message. You can trying doing a object list. [Example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/create-a-list-of-objects-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: I have tried below code.But its returning same results for every record.Any refactored or modern way to write this logic as i written an entry level code.